# How can I test the relationship between events and categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have a dataset comprised of mostly categorical data, in particular, different `name tags` of events that happen within a process. Those are accompanied of their `timestamps` and there are hundreds of unique tags.

I also have some `shutdown` events that happen regularly within said process, in my data, I have around 50 registered shutdowns. Which method can I use to try to identify which tags are influencing the shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

This is a classical application of [Association rule analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), where you want to find what-cause-what.

Answer (score 1):

One option is constructing a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table), aka crosstab, which displays the frequency distribution of categorical variables. From a contingency table, different measures of association can be found. Examples of measures of association include odd ratio, phi coefficient, and uncertainty coefficient.